# Unable to plot histograms in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm unable to plot the histogram in Jupyter notebook. Here's the code below and the error message in response to it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

housing_data = load_boston()
%matplotlib inline
housing_data.hist(bins = 50, figsize = (20, 15))
plt.show()

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in          __getattr__(self, key)
60         try:
---> 61             return self[key]
62         except KeyError:

KeyError: 'hist'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-570a88b85d5d> in <module>()
----> 1 housing_data.hist(bins = 50, figsize = (20, 15))
2 plt.show();

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in    __getattr__(self, key)
 61             return self[key]
 62         except KeyError:
```

---> 63             raise AttributeError(key)
     64 
     65     def **setstate**(self, state):

```
AttributeError: hist
```

I'm new to this and please help me with this.

Comment: You're missing `plot` in your call: `housing_data.plot.hist(...)` should do it

Comment: @busybear, I tried using housing_data.plot.hist() and I get AttributeError: plot

Comment: Ah my bad. I just assumed `housing_data` was a pandas dataframe. The `plot.hist` method is specific for pandas dataframes. `housing_data` is a dictionary, more or less; you need to figure out how you want to deal with that or what data from there you want to plot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

housing_data = load_boston()
%matplotlib inline


pd.DataFrame(housing_data['data']).hist(bins = 50, figsize = (20, 15))
```

you have to access dictionary of numpy array that contains data and than convert it to pandas dataframe in order to use `.hist`

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helped me

Comment: great! Glad that I helped! If you have question feel free to ask. If the question is answered please check the tick under the answer =)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify so I assumed you wanted to plot 'target'?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

housing_data = load_boston()
housing_data_2  = ({'target' : list(housing_data['target'])})
df = pd.DataFrame(data=housing_data_2)
df.plot.hist(bins = 50)
```

[image]